# How to read from a txt file and how to locate it?

Tags: java, android

So in android studio I can right click on drawable folder and go to new -> file and select text and click create. I assume this is basically like a .txt file. So in code how can I read from it? 
I want to use a Scanner

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("what do i type in here?"));
```

Comment: You should really read up on how the whole resource system works in Android, start with this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Resources in the drawable folder are supposed to be images or anything that can be drawn on the screen - hence the name "drawable". You can't just put a text file there and read it.

Comment: Also read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html